# JSON Parse Error: Expecting 'STRING'

Tags: json

I am using [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) to parse some JSON and i keep getting the error:

> Error: Parse error on line 1:
>    [{“    product”: [{“
>   ---^
>   Expecting 'STRING', '}', got 'undefined'

This is the code:

```
[
    {
        “product” :  [ { “code” : “Abc123”, “description” : “Saw blade”, “price” : 34.95 } ],
        “vendor” : [ { “name” : “Acme Hardware”, “state” : “New Jersey” } ]
    },

    {
        “product” :  [ { “code” : “Def456”, “description” : “Hammer”, “price” : 22.51 } ],
    },

    {
        “product” :  [ { “code” : “Ghi789”, “description” : “Wrench”, “price” : 12.15 } ],
        “vendor” : [ { “name” : “Acme Hardware”, “state” : “New Jersey” } ]
    },

    {
        “product” :  [ { “code” : “Jkl012”, “description” : “Pliers”, “price” : 14.54 } ],
        “vendor” : [ { “name” : “Norwegian Tool Suppliers”, “state” : “Kentucky” } ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Don't use smart quotes.

Comment: What is smart quotes?

Comment: Oh ok looked it up and replaced all of them and it worked thanks!

Answer (score 64, accepted):

JSON string literals must use normal quote characters (`"`), not smart quotes (`“”`).

Comment: It's also worth noting that the JSON is still invalid even after converting to normal quote characters. There is a trailing comma after `“price” : 22.51 } ],`. There is no item that follows it, so the comma should be removed.

Comment: I've just made this mistake using single quotes so don't use those either :)

Answer (score 7):

You're using some unicode double quotes characters. Replace them with the normal `"` double quotes.

You also had some extra comma at the end in the second element.

Now it's alright

```
[
    {
        "product" :  [ { "code" : "Abc123", "description" : "Saw blade", "price" : 34.95 } ],
        "vendor" : [ { "name" : "Acme Hardware", "state" : "New Jersey" } ]
    },

    {
        "product" :  [ { "code" : "Def456", "description" : "Hammer", "price" : 22.51 } ]
    },
    {
        "product" :  [ { "code" : "Ghi789", "description" : "Wrench", "price" : 12.15 } ],
        "vendor" : [ { "name" : "Acme Hardware", "state" : "New Jersey" } ]
    },
    {
        "product" : [ { "code" : "Jkl012", "description" : "Pliers", "price" : 14.54 } ],
        "vendor" : [ { "name" : "Norwegian Tool Suppliers", "state" : "Kentucky" } ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

JSON must use normal quote characters("), not smart quotes for(“”) for string literals.

To get the normal quote in JSON data format:
right-click on browser window and select - view page source.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I save the MySQL text format and get the json_decode data

```
[{"5":[29,30,5],"6":[1,2,3],"7":[4,5,6]}]

$row_days= $rows['days'];

var_dump(json_decode($row_days, true));
```

Result array (size=1)

```
0 => array (size=3) 5 => array (size=3) 0 => int 29 1 => int 30 2 => int 5 6 => array (size=3) 0 => int 1 1 => int 2 2 => int 3 7 => array (size=3) 0 => int 4 1 => int 5 2 => int 6
```

Answer (score -2):

For me it was because I was doing the following in an older JavaScript framework. But might not be the case with modern JS frameworks.

```
object.age = 31
```

instead of the better recognized way:

```
object["age"] = 31
```