# Json Error in Eclipse stating Expected value at 1:0

Tags: java, json, eclipse

I have a web application built on Spring Boot and running on a Tomcat 8.5 server. I am trying to create a json object in Eclipse which contains the information about the apis. But it throws an error stating: "Expected value at 1:0" The error gets resolved when I remove the object declaration.

Here the code to my url.json file.

```js
URL =  {
 "FETCH_ALL_USER":"http://localhost:8080/rest/info/",
 "SEND_LEAVE_REQUEST":"http://localhost:8080/rest/find"
}
```

Why do I get this error and how do I solve this.

Comment: That is not valid JSON. Your IDE knows and is telling you.

Comment: @AluanHaddad What do I do to turn it to a valid Json?

Comment: It depends on what it is supposed to be. The closest thing would be `{"URL": {
 "FETCH_ALL_USER":"http://localhost:8080/rest/info/",
 "SEND_LEAVE_REQUEST":"http://localhost:8080/rest/find"
}}` but that is just a guess since it isn't clear what you're trying to achieve. JSON does not have variables.

Comment: Sure. See https://json.org for a full definition (it is short and simple)

Answer (score 1):

We need to enclose the json property in double quotes. save and re-validate the file.

Visit -> [JSON Parse Error: Expecting 'STRING'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34551210/json-parse-error-expecting-string)

solved this issue for me.